# Is there a way to make a CellInfoNr to CellSignalStrengthNr?

Tags: android, cellinfo, 5g

I'm looking for a documentation for output a inner cellinfo like RSRP, RSRQ, SINR, RSSI.

And I want to look upon 5G(New Radio) data.

```
cellRSRP = ((CellSignalStrengthNr) ((CellInfoNr) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength()).getCsiRsrp();
```

This is what I've tried to get a cellRSRP of 5G.
It quite a lot similar to get LTE data.

---

And this doesn't work, because I deliberately cast

```
(CellSignalStrengthNr)
```

on this code

```
((CellInfoNr) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength())
```

Since the `getCellSignalStrength()` doesn't return `CellSignalStrengthNr` data,
(It returns `CellSignalStrength`)

so I just cast on the code, no error detected, everything was seemed to going fine.

But It was not and I came here to ask a question.

So, in a nutshell,

1. Is there a normal way to make `CellSignalStrengthNr` without casting?
2. Or should I try more different ways with casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to code in android.telephony,
CellSignalStrengthNr extends CellSignalStrength.

So, I don't think you need to make CellSignalStrength to CellSignalStrengthNr.
If "telephonyManager.requestCellInfoUpdate()" returns CellInfoNr, CellSignalStrength in CellInfoNr is CellSignalStrengthNr.

just do..

```
CellInfoNr cellinfo = ((CellInfoNr) cellInfo)
CellSignalStrengthNr signal = ((CellSignalStrengthNr) cellinfo.getCellSignalStrength())
```